# Entrando em if errado

Tags: javascript, if, return, condição

Eu fiz esse code e o esperado é que ele me retornasse 'Jedi Master', mas sempre me retorna 'Intermediário'. Primeiro tinha feito usando switch-case ao invés de if-else e ele sempre me retornava 'Inválido' (no caso do default).

```
function experiencia(anos) {
        if (anos <= 1) {
                return 'Iniciante'
        } else if (1 < anos <= 3) {
                return 'Intermediário'
        } else if (3 < anos <= 6) {
                return 'Avançado'
        } else if (anos >=  7) {
                return 'Jedi Master'
        } else {
                return 'Inválido'
        }
};

        var anosEstudo = 7;

        console.log(experiencia(anosEstudo))
```

Comment: Eu teria que construir if (anos <= 3 && < 1) então? E faz alguma ideia do porquê de retornar esse caso?

Comment: `1 < anos && anos <= 3`. Sim.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 5):

Essa sintaxe não faz sentido, pode fazer o código muito mais simples e aí correto. Você só pode fazer uma comparação por vez, se tiver que compor duas comparações tem que usar um operador `||` ou `&&` conforme a necessidade, mas nesse caso nem tem necessidade.

Depois que passa pelo primeiro `if` já é certo que o número não menor ou igual a 1 então não tem porque verificar isso novamente no segundo, só tirando essa parte já resolve o problema.

O mesmo vale para o `if` seguinte.

Também aconselho colocar `;` no fim de cada *statement* mesmo que não precise, a regra de onde pode e não pode é confusa, seja consistente e mantenha a legibilidade, coloque sempre.

O problema que você teve é parecido com o que deu errado na comparação composta. JavaScript é uma linguagem muito permissiva.

Não sei onde viu essa sintaxe, talvez em Python, que realmente funciona da forma correta porque é um operador composto. No seu código são dois operadores independentes, explico.

Seu código, no segundo `if` está fazendo a seguinte comparação em primeiro lugar, só ela:

```
1 < anos
```

Essa expressão dá um resultado `false` ou `true`, porque o operador relacional `<` como todos os outros sempre retornando um booleano, portando um desses dois valores.

Em seguida ele fará a comparação do resultado dessa expressão com o resto, portanto ele faz assim:

```
(1 < anos) <= 3
```

Vamos supor que deu `true` (seu exemplo dá, 1 é menor que 7):

```
(true) <= 3
```

Só que isso não pode ser comparado diretamente. Porém JS tem tipagem fraca e tenta coagir o valor para algo que possa ser usado, então para comparar certo o JS faz assim (o `true` sempre vale 1):

```
1 <= 3
```

O primeiro operando sofre a conversão para ser compatível com o segundo. Sempre que há uma comparação que envolve um número e um booleano o booleano é convertido ([especificação](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison)).

E aí o resultado final é `true`, portanto cai nesse `if`. Não é o que esperava.

Assim funciona:

```js
function experiencia(anos) {
    if (anos <= 1) return 'Iniciante';
    else if (anos <= 3) return 'Intermediário';
    else if (anos <= 6) return 'Avançado';
    else if (anos >=  7) return 'Jedi Master';
    else return 'Inválido';
}
console.log(experiencia(7));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/RelatitionalOperator.js).

Comment: Muito obrigado! Não queria ser o mais eficiente por isso escrevi ele buscando a variável e não direto no console.log; acabei colocando a opção 'inválido' caso o input não fosse um número num caso hipotético. Também acabei escrevendo em forma de intervalos porque achei que o programa não fosse saber qual condição triggar (já que, por exemplo, para 2 tanto 'anos <= 3' quanto 'anos <=6' são válidos).

Comment: Faz sentido, mudei isso. Ele sabe, não é aleatório, é na sequência.

Answer (score 0):

Atualmente o javascript não possui suporte a esta sintaxe, deve ser feito da seguinte maneira:

```
   function experiencia(anos) {
    if (anos <= 1) {
            return 'Iniciante'
    } else if (anos > 1 && anos <= 3) {
            return 'Intermediário'
    } else if (anos > 3 && anos <= 6) {
            return 'Avançado'
    } else if (anos >=  7) {
            return 'Jedi Master'
    } else {
            return 'Inválido'
    }
};
```

Uma sugestão de melhoria é que com essas condições atuais o caso 'Inválido' nunca será executado (caso a função seja chamada sempre com inteiros), e pode ser removido.

Porém é possível imprimir o resultado `Inválido`. Caso você faça a chamada da função da seguinte maneira:

```
experiencia('a')
```

> "Inválido"

Que não sei se faz sentido para a resolução do seu problema.